# Jenkins Retry before Pipeline execution

Tags: jenkins

Is it posible to have some kind of retry mechanism before the pipeline executes?

In my setup i have a Jenkins and git server. The network is unstable. The pipeline code is in git, but the git-server is sometimes not reachable. In that case the pipeline just fails with a timeout. Some kind of "retry in some minutes" would be nice here.

I reaseached a bit, but found no plugin or config in Jenkins to solve it.

IMPORTANT: all kind of Retry inside the pipeline won´t help here, as the job fails on getting the pipeline code.

Comment: Will [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/naginator/) be useful?

Comment: If i got the plugin right, it adds a Post-Action on a "Free Style"-Softwareprojekt in Jenkins. In my setup i have multiple Jenkins-Pipelines using "Pipeline script from CSM". The plugin doesn´t work here.

Answer (score 2):

I whould just think of these three options of the job's [general build triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weO2N.png) configuration, but these also depend on your desired job type:

1. let the job look for scm changes by cron.
2. trigger the job periodically by cron.
3. trigger the job from an external script/tool that checks for the network connection stability / availability.

1 and 2 with give you the "retry" behaviour by default.

Generally all three should fit for simple pipeline job.
Multibranch pipelines or jobs that are newly created, might not have success with option 1.

Secondly I whould suggest to utilize [lightweight checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsDeW.png) of the pipeline script. This whould reduce the amount of network time / bandwith to get the pipeline definition at least.

Comment: Thanks! I think option 3 is the way to go. If i get somethink to work, i´ll post it here.

Option 1 and 2 won´t work in this specific setup, because the pipeline are triggered by an external system on demand.

Lightweight Checkout is already set ;)